# Awk multiplication gives zero

Tags: macos, bash, awk

I am a bit new to using awk. My goal is to create a bash function of the form:

```
myfunction file column value
```

That takes the given column number in file, multiplies it by value and rewrites the file. For now I have written the following:

```
function multiply_column {
 file=$1
 column=$2
 value=$3
 awk -F" " '{print $col*mul}' col=$column mul=$value $file
}
```

My file looks like this:

```
   0.400000E+15    0.168933E+00   -0.180294E-44    0.168933E+00
   0.401000E+15    0.167689E+00   -0.181383E-44    0.167689E+00
   0.402000E+15    0.166502E+00   -0.182475E-44    0.166502E+00
   0.403000E+15    0.165371E+00   -0.183569E-44    0.165371E+00
   0.404000E+15    0.164298E+00   -0.184666E-44    0.164298E+00
   0.405000E+15    0.163284E+00   -0.185766E-44    0.163284E+00
   0.406000E+15    0.162328E+00   -0.186868E-44    0.162328E+00
   0.407000E+15    0.161431E+00   -0.187972E-44    0.161431E+00
   0.408000E+15    0.160593E+00   -0.189080E-44    0.160593E+00
   0.409000E+15    0.159816E+00   -0.190189E-44    0.159816E+00
   0.410000E+15    0.159099E+00   -0.191302E-44    0.159099E+00
   0.411000E+15    0.158442E+00   -0.192416E-44    0.158442E+00
   0.412000E+15    0.157847E+00   -0.193534E-44    0.157847E+00
   0.413000E+15    0.157312E+00   -0.194653E-44    0.157312E+00
   0.414000E+15    0.156840E+00   -0.195775E-44    0.156840E+00
   0.415000E+15    0.156429E+00   -0.196899E-44    0.156429E+00
   0.416000E+15    0.156081E+00   -0.198026E-44    0.156081E+00
   0.417000E+15    0.155796E+00   -0.199154E-44    0.155796E+00
   0.418000E+15    0.155573E+00   -0.200285E-44    0.155573E+00
   0.419000E+15    0.155413E+00   -0.201418E-44    0.155413E+00
   0.420000E+15    0.155318E+00   -0.202554E-44    0.155318E+00
   0.421000E+15    0.155285E+00   -0.203691E-44    0.155285E+00
   0.422000E+15    0.155318E+00   -0.204831E-44    0.155318E+00
   0.423000E+15    0.155414E+00   -0.205973E-44    0.155414E+00
   0.424000E+15    0.155575E+00   -0.207116E-44    0.155575E+00
   0.425000E+15    0.155802E+00   -0.208262E-44    0.155802E+00
```

I managed to just print the first column, but when I multiply it with my value, awk gives me 0. I tried my function with other files where data was formatted differently, and it worked perfectly. I also tried to combine it with bc, without any success.

Does anyone see why in this case awk gives 0 ?

Thanks in advance !

######### EDIT

I just found out that if my data file uses commas and not dots (i.e. 0,400000E+15 instead of 0.400000E+15), my function works fine. So somehow, somewhere, something is configured to understand commas as the scientific notation separator instead of dots. Does that ring a bell to anyone ?

Comment: Hmm, works fine for me...

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use Mac OSX. Could that be related ?

Comment: How do you call the function `multiply_column`  exactly? Which arguments?

Comment: It works fine on OSX. Btw, `awk`'s default separator is already a space, so you can omit `-F" "`. Also, you should double-quote `$file` where you use it in case it has a space.

Comment: Thank you for the advices ! I put this function in my .bash_profile, and then call:

    myfunction myfile 1 2.0

which should multiply the first column by 2, if I am not wrong

Comment: Yep, that should work (and does on my system). You're going to have to provide us with a reproducible test case where it doesn't work.

Comment: Just so you know, your function syntax (using the `function` keyword) is bash-specific - you can make your function more portable by changing it to `multiply_column() {` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `LC_ALL=C` before executing your script to get the most commonly expected behavior for this and other locale-dependent issues. See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Locales. Also don't pointlessly set `FS` to it's default value, do quote your shell variables (google that if you don't know why), and do fix the way you are setting your variables to use the form that produces the most intuitive results (see http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24):

```
LC_ALL=C awk -v col="$column" -v mul="$value" '{print $col*mul}' "$file"
```

Read the book Effective Awk programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Which variable out of the `LC_*` variables does `awk` use for that? I have a ["mixed" locale](http://pastebin.com/H8VHXVbx), where `LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8` and the script from the question works.

Comment: @hek2mgl Are you using GNU awk?

Comment: @hek2mgl if I understand your question - awk doesn't use any of them for that because by default `.` is the decimal point unless `LC_NUMERIC` is populated AND `--use-lc-numeric` is set on the command line. That's so gawk by default behaves as desired for the common case of people in a locale where `,` is defined to be the decimal point for their locale but their input data uses `.`s (which is the OPs situation apparently but he's not using gawk or it would have behaved as desired).

Comment: @jlliagre Yes, I'm using gawk. EdMorten: ok, that answers my question. I was just wondering why I can't reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is a mismatch between the locale used to create the data file and you current one.

For example the French locale and similar ones use the comma as their decimal separator while the dot is the most widely used, and is also the POSIX default.

If you want for commas to be accepted as decimal separators, you might workaround the issue like this:

```
LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF-8 awk '{print $col*mul}' col="$column" mul="$value" "$file"
```

Note that this won't work as is with GNU `awk` which doesn't honor the numeric locale setting by default. You would need to use the `--use-lc-numeric` flag to override.

Alternatively, if you want for dots to be accepted as decimal separators but your current locale is using commas and you are not using GNU awk, you can run this:

```
LC_NUMERIC=C awk '{print $col*mul}' col="$column" mul="$value" "$file"
```

Comment: You can check your locale using the command `locale` by the way.

Comment: My locale is `LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8`, which is also using `,` as the decimal separator. It works for me.

Comment: @hek2mgl What works for you? The posted datafile ? The actual datafile ? With GNU awk ? Unix awk ?

Comment: Ok I did not know about that kind of stuff. Your answer did not *exactly* solve my problem (my original data file is not written as  0,400000E+15 but as 0.400000E+15, as mentioned in the question, however awk was awaiting a comma), but straightforwardly pointed me to the solution: I just reset the LC_NUMERIC environment variable in my .bash_profile.

LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
export LC_NUMERIC

Thank you very much for your kind help !

Comment: While setting LC_NUMERIC would be the right solution if you have an English locale and French data, it's the wrong solution if you have a French locale and English data. You should be setting `LC_ALL=C` instead. The reason is that setting LC_NUMERIC to French for one specific data set (as @jlliagre thought you had) is fine but you don't want to have to set all of your `LC_` vars individually to English and you will have far fewer surprises if you just use the common, ISO default locale (i.e. `C`) for all of your text manipulation.

Comment: user3237302, I overlook the "if" in your edit, i.e. I read "I just found out that my data file uses..." while you wrote "I just found out that if my data file uses...", that's the reason why my initial suggestion was reversed.